# Multiple device view on Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

Is there any way that I can quickly see how my view is going to look in different scales? On Xcode there is a preview feature in storyboard mode, just checking if there is anything like that but in Android Studio or even third party...

[image: multiple screen sizes on xcode]

Thanks in advance, any help/suggestion/pro-tip ;) is appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you know to go to the xml file and open the design tab of the layout . and now you can see only single preview of the layout in device.

- Then look to your top bar on the design window which contains app theme , the android version and device name. (below is a screen shot).

[image: Look at the Nexus 4]

- Now all you have to do is open the drop down which contains device names (in my screen shot Nexus 4) and go to bottom . you will see preview all screens . this will show all the screen preview.

[image: Preview all screens]

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: So simple! Thanks Sagar, its even better than Xcode because I don't have to manually add the devices I want in.

Comment: but this is not multiple view!

Answer (score 21):

There is menu called "**Layout validation**" where you can preview all the screen on Android studio 4.0.

Comment: where is that menu?

Comment: EDIT: Layout Validation is a panel to the right of your designer (below gradle's panel)

Comment: Holy moly this is awesome !

Comment: I knew it existed, but couldn't find it. That is such an unintuitive spot to put it. Thanks for pointing it out for me!

Answer (score 3):

**"Layout validation" tool window rely on context to be visible**

**Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1**

in text editor mode  **layout validation** is not visible at the very right of the ide

[image: editor mode]

But if you are in design mode and working on a layout (not a path nor icon ) . **Layout validation** will appear in between gradle and device manager tools

[image: editor mode]

Now you can work with  **layout validation** tool window .

[image: layout validation]

Answer (score 2):

*Multi Preview*, which is like this, is a feature of Android Studio 3.6+

Comment: I've seen in it mac, but is it available in Ubuntu? Cause I can't seem to find it in my Android Studio 3.6.1 and Ubuntu 19.10

Comment: I think you need 4.1 for Multi preview "New features in Android Studio Preview ... Android Studio 4.1 is currently in the Canary and Dev channels, and Android Studio 4.0 is currently in the Beta channel." and then on the page they list that multi preview thin
https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features#4.0-multi-preview